# EVE Online - Aggression Mechanics

Tags: eve-online

I have a few questions regarding the latest aggression mechanics. Lets say I'm with a buddy down in the ice fields, and gankers show up and start shooting him. If I were to apply shield/armor rep to my buddy in an effort to keep him from getting ganked, will I get a suspect flag and/or lose security status?

I know you get the suspect flag for repping the criminal/suspect, but what about his victim/target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a suspect flag, because the aggressor - although being flagged as a criminal now - won't be able to shoot you without getting flagged once again. Note that this doesn't apply to active war targets. Fighting war targets won't create limited engagements, as such you can start repairing straight away without having to worry (about getting flagged; you should still keep an eye at the war target).

This sounds odd, but it's there to avoid possible abuses of the system.

However, there's a nice and simple workaround: Get your own limited engagement first!

You can do this by aggressing the (now criminal) pilot (e.g. by sending your drones, shooting him or doing some kind of EWAR). Once you've got your limited engagement, you can repair your buddy without being flagged.

Overall, I probably wouldn't worry too much about this due to one simple reason: CONCORD will intercept the aggressor if you're in high sec, that means he's got only a very limited amount of time to do any damage to your buddy. With this in mind there are usually just two extremes:

- The attacker does enough damage to take out your buddy with 1-2 salvoes. There's really nothing you can do to repair him in time, even though Shield Transporters start healing immediately.
- The attacker doesn't do enough damage, which will result in your buddy surviving anyway.

In low sec, this is - of course - a bit different, but at the same time a suspect flag won't be as significant there anyway (people could shoot you anyway by going suspect on their own).

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering based on the [Dev Blog about Crimewatch 2.0](http://community.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&nbid=73443), I haven't tried this out in practice myself.

When a suspect or criminal attacks an illegal target, both pilots get a limited engagement, to allow the attacking suspect or criminal to defend themselves without committing further crimes.

Assisting a pilot in a limited engagement results in a suspect flag, but no security status penalty according to the [diagram from the dev blog](http://cdn1.eveonline.com/www/newssystem/media/63443/1/logo2_actions2flags.png). Having a suspect flag means you can be freely attacked by any player.

[CCP Masterplan confirms in a forum post](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=2003428#post2003428) that interfering in a limited engagement will result in a suspect flag.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient thread, I know, but since both other answers have a slight issue, felt I should clarify:

If you remote repair someone who is being ganked, you will not go suspect unless the person who is being ganked has fought back. In other words, if a miner uses their drones to attack the ganker back, then a 3rd party would have to set safety to yellow to be able to rep the miner.

This is because if the miner (or a freighter, bowhead, etc. that can't fight back) has not fought back, they are not in a limited engagement and thus can be repped freely without the neutral logi going flashy yellow.

In short, if they're in a limited engagement and you try to rep them with green safety, you will not be able to until and unless you set your safety to yellow.